# is a prescription +1.00 diopter lens the same as over-the-counter lens in +1.00 magnifying glasses?

Tags: optometry

is a prescription for +1.00 diopter lens to treat far sightedness the same optical correction as an over-the-counter +1.00 magnifying glasses?  Or do the "magnifying" glasses actually magnify like a magnifier lenses does?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question but I use OTC glasses and they are worse than useless for distance vision. Beyond about a meter they distort vision severely.

Comment: I understand that reading glasses won't help with near sightedness, but needed to know if an over the counter "magnifying glasses" were the same as glasses for Far Sightedness (given there is no astigmatism involved).  In other words, is a +1.00 in prescription lenses the same as an over the counter +1.00 "magnifying glasses"  What is confusing me is why they are called magnifying glasses, yet the prescription glasses are not called magnifying glasses (that I know of).  Also, I had another technical reason to find out.

Comment: I'm guessing you're not in the US? I'm not familiar with the term  "magnifying glasses" so that probably means others aren't either. You might want to clarify in your question exactly what you mean by that term.